# perl socket client/server queuing up the packets

Tags: perl, sockets, tcp, client-server, cpan

I am working on vehicle tracking system, where in a GPS device(socket client is programmed) communicates with socket server to send GPS co-ordinates, etc. The socket server parses the data and is sent via get method to http web services for further processing. I tried simulating 50 clients locally to study the socket server behaviour. Unfortunately, I see a delay in parsing/getting the data, even though all the clients were fired at the same/different time. But My requirement, is to have first come first served, but in this context, it doesn't seem so. Does this need anything to deal with the `Timeout` parameter in `new IO::Socket::INET ();`? Below is my socket server listening to port 11050.

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
use IO::Socket::INET;

$| = 1;

my ($socket,$client_socket);
my ($peeraddress,$peerport);
my $LOGFILE="/home/nuthan/program/input.log";
open (LOG,">>$LOGFILE");
$socket = new IO::Socket::INET ( LocalHost => '192.168.1.110', 
                                 LocalPort => '11050', Proto => 'tcp',
                                 Listen => 500, Reuse => 1,  
                                 Blocking => 0, Timeout => 2 )
    or die "ERROR in Socket Creation : $!\n";
while(1) {
    # waiting for new client connection.

    $client_socket = $socket->accept();
    #print "SOCKET $client_socket SOCKET\n";
    if (! $client_socket){
        next;
    }

    # Received from Client :
    #356823033046306##0#0000#AUT#1#V#07734.7000,E,1259.5355,N,000.00,288#211011#085017##
    #EMI's code(15 numbers)#username#status#password#data type#data volume#base station  information#longitude, E,latitude, N, speed, direction#date#time##
    $client_socket->recv($data,1500);
    print  "Received from Client : $data\n";
    #print LOG "Received from Client : $data\n";
    my ($blah,$EMI,$username,$status,$password,$data_type,$data_volume,
        $base_station_info,$dir,$date,$time,$blah1)=split(/\#/,$data);
    new_do_get($EMI,$dir,$date,$time);
}


sub new_do_get(){
    print "In new_do_get\n";
    my ($EMI,$dir,$date,$time) = @_;
    my ($longitude,$e,$latitude,$n,$speed,$direction)=split(/,/,$dir);
    my $url = "http://192.168.1.110:8080/prototype/socket/location.php?"
      . "ln=$longitude&lt=$latitude&imei=$EMI&d=$date&o=0&v=$speed&t=$time";
    # print "$url\n";
    use LWP::Simple;
    my $content = get $url;
    die "Couldn't get $url" unless defined $content;
}

$socket->close();
close LOG;
```

Comment: You're measuring too much code for the effect you are claiming. Take out the HTTP request part so that you are independent from the PHP listener and the network in-between. Put in some line-by-line logging with timestamps. - Am I correct when I guess that the 50 client simulation fakes the GPS device? If yes, also post that code.

Comment: Do you realize that if one client decides to just sit there with the socket open, not sending anything, that your server will sit there and wait for it—ignoring all other clients? You need to either fork off for each client or use `select`. Instead of doing the latter, consider [`POE`](http://p3rl.org/POE).

Comment: thnx @derobert i realized it was waiting for long time. After looking around, came to know with such sheer volume of clients, Multi-threading perl socket would suffice the problem. I have posted that code below. Now, i am not sure where to read/receive the data.

Comment: @nuthan: you'd do it in the anonymous subroutine passed to spawn. You shouldn't be doing in the parent process at all. Some reason not to use POE?

Answer (score 0):

**Multi-threading socket server**

After looking around, realized, with such sheer volume of clients, Multi-threading perl socket will suffice the problem. Hope this might help somebody.
[a link](http://perl.active-venture.com/pod/perlipc-sockets.html)!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -Tw
use strict;
BEGIN { $ENV{PATH} = '/usr/ucb:/bin' }
use Socket;
use Carp;
my $EOL = "\015\012";

sub spawn;  # forward declaration
sub logmsg { print "$0 $$: @_ at ", scalar localtime, "\n" }

my $port = shift || 11051;
my $proto = getprotobyname('tcp');

($port) = $port =~ /^(\d+)$/                        or die "invalid port";

socket(Server, PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, $proto)    || die "socket: $!";
setsockopt(Server, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR,
                pack("l", 1))   || die "setsockopt: $!";
bind(Server, sockaddr_in($port, INADDR_ANY))    || die "bind: $!";
listen(Server,SOMAXCONN)                || die "listen: $!";

logmsg "server started on port $port";

my $waitedpid = 0;
my $paddr;

use POSIX ":sys_wait_h";
sub REAPER {
my $child;
    while (($waitedpid = waitpid(-1,WNOHANG)) > 0) {
    logmsg "reaped $waitedpid" . ($? ? " with exit $?" : '');
}
$SIG{CHLD} = \&REAPER;  # loathe sysV
}

$SIG{CHLD} = \&REAPER;

for ( $waitedpid = 0;
  ($paddr = accept(Client,Server)) || $waitedpid;
  $waitedpid = 0, close Client)
{
read(Client, $buffer, 1000);
next if $waitedpid and not $paddr;
my($port,$iaddr) = sockaddr_in($paddr);
my $name = gethostbyaddr($iaddr,AF_INET);

logmsg "connection from $name [",
    inet_ntoa($iaddr), "]
$buffer
 #your data in $buffer
    at port $port";

spawn sub {
    $|=1;
    print "Hello there, $name, it's now ", scalar localtime, $EOL;
        or confess "can't exec fortune: $!";
};

}

sub spawn {
my $coderef = shift;

unless (@_ == 0 && $coderef && ref($coderef) eq 'CODE') {
    confess "usage: spawn CODEREF";
}

my $pid;
if (!defined($pid = fork)) {
    logmsg "cannot fork: $!";
    return;
} elsif ($pid) {
    logmsg "begat $pid";
    return; # I'm the parent
}
# else I'm the child -- go spawn

open(STDIN,  "<&Client")   || die "can't dup client to stdin";
open(STDOUT, ">&Client")   || die "can't dup client to stdout";
## open(STDERR, ">&STDOUT") || die "can't dup stdout to stderr";
exit &$coderef();
}
```